# Fitch proof for $(p \implies (q \implies r)) \implies ((p \implies q) \implies (p \implies r))$ with no premises

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I'm having trouble solving [this problem](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/exercises/exercise_04_07.html) using the Fitch system. As I understand Fitch, if the goal has the form $(φ \implies ψ)$, it is often good to assume $φ$ and prove $ψ$ and then use Implication Introduction to derive the goal. Since there are no premises, to prove $(p \implies (q \implies r)) \implies ((p \implies q) \implies (p \implies r))$ with the Fitch system, I'll need to assume the antecedent $(p \implies (q \implies r))$ and use Implication introduction to derive the consequent $((p \implies q) \implies (p \implies r))$. I'm stuck though as using Stanford's Fitch system, assuming $(p \implies (q \implies r))$ results in $p(q)$ and assuming $p \implies q \implies r$  results in $p$. How should I think about this problem so I can resolve the proof?

Comment: Of note: part of my problem was using the symbols (p ⇒ (q ⇒ r)) in the Stanford Fitch system engine and not =>

Comment: When I click on your link I get a "Show Answer" button. Don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $p \to (q \to r)$ --- assumed [a]

2) $p \to q$ --- assumed [b]

3) $p$ --- assumed [c]

4) $q$ --- from 3) and 2) by $\to$-elim

5) $q \to r$ --- from 3) and 1) by $\to$-elim

6) $r$ --- from 4) and 5) by $\to$-elmi

7) $p \to r$ --- from 3) and 6) by $\to$-intro, discharging [b]

> 8) $(p \to q) \to (p \to r)$ --- from 2) and 7) by $\to$-intro, discharging [b]
>
> > 9) $(p \to (q \to r)) \to [(p \to q) \to (p \to r)]$ --- from 1) and 8) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

As you can see, we have to assume all the antecedents of the conditionals involved.

Comment: This helped a lot: "we have to assume all the antecedents of the conditionals involved" especially as it was not covered here: http://intrologic.stanford.edu/notes/chapter_04.html

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy - be aware, please ... that is not a "formal rule". It works here because we have only conditionals. But in general, it is a good approach whenever we want to prove something of the form: $\varphi \to \psi$.

Comment: Also very helpful. Can you recommend any resources for better understanding Fitch system? I am struggling with the Stanford online course as the reading material is... less than thorough.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy - in general, [Chiswell & Hodges](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA1) is a good textbook based on Natural Deduction.

Comment: [Peter Smith's Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover) is also good.

Comment: An you can try with Frederic Brenton Fitch, [Symbolic Logic: An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=a3wIAQAAIAAJ) (1952)

Comment: Thanks, [Mathematical Logic](https://www.ibisc.univ-evry.fr/~belardinelli/Documents/Logique/Mathematical-Logic-ChiswellHodges.pdf) looks like a great read.