# How do I prove a statement of the form $(P \implies Q)\implies(R \implies S)?$

Tags: calculus, logic

I know $P \implies Q,$ I need to prove that $(P\implies Q)$ implies that $(R\implies S)$

Should I assume $R$ is true? [And $R$ is not the same as $P,$ or $Q$]

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249236/fitch-proof-for-p-implies-q-implies-r-implies-p-implies-q-implies?rq=1)

Comment: There are at least 5 ways to prove $A \implies B$: (1) Assume $A$ is true and prove $B$, (2) assume $B$ is false and prove $A$ is false, (3) prove both $A$ and $B$ are true, (4) prove we cannot have both $A$ is true and $B$ is false, or (5) prove $A$ is false.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - this does indeed sense from the truth tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first assume $P \implies Q$ is true. Now you want to show $R \implies S$ is true.
For this, you further assume $R$ is true and use $P \implies Q$ to show that $S$ is true.

For example, let

$P: A$ is the mother of $B$

$Q: C$ is a sister of $B$

$R: B$ is a son of $A$

$S: A$ is the mother of $C$

We want to show $(P \implies Q)\implies(R \implies S)$

Suppose, $P\implies Q$ and $R$ is true. So, we have that $B$ is a son of $A.$ This means that $A$ is a mother of $B.$ Since, $P \implies Q$ this means that $C$ is a sister of $B.$ Hence, $A$ must be the mother of $C.$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for this - your explanation and example really cleared up the issue for me.

Comment: @cos90 Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to show that  $R \implies S$, you assume $R$ is true and prove $S$ is true. In the process you may or may not use $P \implies Q$.